# packages have been unpacked but not yet configured

Tags: installation, network-manager, dependencies

I am stuck with this weired issue. I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Sudo dpkg --audit

Output is

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
network-manager-dbg:i386 network management framework (debugging symbols)
network-manager:i386 network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
network-manager-gnome:i386 network management framework (GNOME frontend)
```

Not sure what to do.

I have also tried apt-get -f install

Output is

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
network-manager-dbg:i386 network management framework (debugging symbols)
network-manager:i386 network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
network-manager-gnome:i386 network management framework (GNOME frontend)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-bluetooth : Breaks: network-manager-gnome:i386 (= 0.9.4) but it is not installed
Breaks: network-manager-gnome:i386 (= 2.4) but it is not installed
Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (>= 0.88) but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not installed
Depends: libgudev-1.0-0:i386 (>= 147) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-3-200:i386 (>= 3.2.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-genl-3-200:i386 (>= 3.2.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libnl-route-3-200:i386 but it is not installed
Depends: libnm-glib4:i386 (>= 0.9.4.0~git201203162258.69247a0) but it is not installed
Depends: libnm-util2:i386 (>= 0.9.3.995+git201203081848.bba834f) but it is not installed
Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0:i386 (>= 0.99) but it is not installed
Depends: wpasupplicant:i386 (>= 0.7.3-1) but it is not installed
Depends: isc-dhcp-client:i386 (>= 4.1.1-P1-4) but it is not installed
Depends: dnsmasq-base:i386 but it is not installed
Depends: iputils-arping:i386 but it is not installed
Recommends: network-manager-pptp:i386 but it is not installed
Recommends: ppp:i386 (>= 2.4.5) but it is not installed
Recommends: iptables:i386 but it is not installed
Recommends: modemmanager:i386 but it is not installed
Breaks: network-manager-gnome:i386 (= 1.29.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not installed
Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (>= 0.78) but it is not installed
Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
Depends: libgconf2-4:i386 (>= 2.27.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libglade2-0:i386 (>= 1:2.6.1) but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.18.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libgnome-bluetooth7:i386 (>= 2.27.8) but it is not installable
Depends: libgnome-keyring0:i386 (>= 2.20.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libnm-glib2:i386 (>= 0.8~rc2~git.20091229t135236.302e62d) but it is not installable
Depends: libnm-util1:i386 (>= 0.8~a~git.20090930t162132.866d48b) but it is not installable
Depends: libnotify1:i386 (>= 0.4.5) but it is not installable
Depends: libnotify1-gtk2.10:i386 but it is not installable
Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.6.27) but it is not installed
Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not installed
Depends: gksu:i386 but it is not installed
Depends: mobile-broadband-provider-info:i386 (>= 20090622) but it is not installable
Recommends: notification-daemon:i386
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure network-manager-dbg:i386 network-manager:i386 network-manager-gnome:i386
```